# How to find unused template variables in Django

Tags: django, code-cleanup

I'm doing clean up on django code - my [IDE](http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/) can easily detect unused variables etc in Python code, but I haven't found a way to find unused template variables - it would be much easier to clean up the view code if I could find out what values in the context dictionary are not accessed by the templates.

Is there a tool for this?

**EDIT**: I am looking for an *offline* solution, a static code analysis tool or such. While the [paranoid templates](http://excess.org/article/2012/04/paranoid-django-templates/) solution suggested below is better than nothing, it is not optimal because there are multiple `{% if ... %}` branches in templates and futhermore, would require testing all the views (in all use cases) in order to find all the unreferenced variables.

Comment: You can see variables with [django-debug-toolbar](https://github.com/django-debug-toolbar/django-debug-toolbar/) although it doesn't distinguish between used and unused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [*paranoid django templates*](http://excess.org/article/2012/04/paranoid-django-templates/) solution:

```
class ParanoidContextProxy(object):
    """
    This is a poor-man's proxy for a context instance.

    Make sure template rendering stops immediately on a KeyError.
    """
    def __init__(self, context):
        self.context = context
        self.seen_keys = set()

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        self.seen_keys.add(key)
        try:
            return self.context[key]
        except KeyError:
            raise ParanoidKeyError('ParanoidKeyError: %r' % (key,))

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return getattr(self.context, name)
    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        self.context[key] = value
    def __delitem__(self, key):
        del self.context[key]
```

Comment: Err .. this is basically the opposite of what the OP wanted, right?

Comment: Ah, because you didn't include the `paranoid_context_manager` function, which is the necessary part to actually use `seen_keys`.

Comment: I awarded you the bounty, but I'm still looking for a nicer approach. I guess I'll have to create the tool myself...